# Cider - Process Question

Tags: cider

I have been making Beer and Wine for quite some time and am familiar with the processes and am pleased with my results.  I have really taking a shine to hard cider, I made a batch last year using BA-11 yeast, adding only yeast nutrient and pectin enzyme to the raw cider.  Results are excellent IMO.

My question is, I just started a 3 gallon batch in my large mouth 6 1/2 gallon primary. Usually I treat it like wine, transfer to a secondary, clear, rack, top off and then after a few months prime and bottle.

In light of this, can I treat this like beer?  That is, ferment, give it about two weeks to clear in the primary, then rack onto the priming solution and bottle, allowing it to age in the bottle for few months before consuming?
All in all I'm trying to speed up the process from treating it like wine and more like a beer process.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear, rack, top off"? Specifically "top off"? Do you add water to the 3 gallons after fermentation to fill the 6 gal?

Comment: I've either cleared cider with time, or more efficiently with gelatin as a fining agent, settling the yeast and other sediment to the bottom of the fermenter, then racking  (siphoning), off the clear cider to another container for aging.  I fill the void (top off), in the container with past made still cider to remove air space. Once aged  sufficiently, I either bottle it still (uncarbonated) or prime and bottle for a bubbly dry cider.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Cider is often handled exactly like beer.